# New DOMDocument() in PHP 4

Tags: php, sql, mysql, xml, phpmyadmin

I've make an application in PHP that uses DOMDocument() in PHP 5.

The problem is that my server uses PHP 4 and DOM object is not recognized. What can I do?

Can I download any kind of software and put it in my server and use include?
Which one?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If PHP4 is a given unchangeable fact then please see my answer below - otherwise please follow the suggestion to update your server to PHP5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DOM XML extension in PHP4: http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.domxml.php.

Please note that the API is not compatible with the [PHP5 DOM extension](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5

Have your server admin upgrade your server.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly encourage you to try to get your ISP to [GOPHP5](http://www.gophp5.org/).

Comment: Or switch to an ISP who has already done so.  PHP4 is no longer supported as of 8/8/2008.